# How can i compare a variable (whose value was taken using combo box) of sqlite3 table to a variable (again taken value using combo box) in pyqt5?

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5

In my PyQt5 GUI, I have created a table using SQLite3. The table has different column, one is 'semester' for which combo box is used to take input. I want to print out information of only those rows which have the same semester value as another user input (taken using a combo box). While taking input i wrote the code as following-

```
semester = self.semesterinput.itemText(self.semesterinput.currentIndex()) #used to take input
```

Code portion for the query-

```
result = self.c.execute("SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY reg_no) AS serial,reg_no,name,semester FROM socRecord WHERE semester = "+ str(name_of_semester))
```

I am getting 'unrecognized token' error. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to concatenate since your code will be susceptible to SQL Injection in addition to generating other problems, instead you must use the placeholders:

```
semester = self.semesterinput.currentText()
result = self.c.execute(
    "SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY reg_no) AS serial,reg_no,name,semester FROM socRecord WHERE semester = ? ",
    (semester,),
)
```